# Unit testing logic in controller OnActionExecuting event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

There is a custom logic to set the page title in my controller's OnActionExecuting event which sets default value for title if it is not set using an attribute on action methods:

```
[PageTitle("Overriden page title")]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}

protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    //Page title
    var title = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false);
    if (title.Length == 1)
        ViewBag.Title = ((PageTitleAttribute)(title[0])).Parameter;
    else
        ViewBag.Title = "Default Website Title";
}
```

How can I unit test this functionality?

Comment: Why not implementing the above OnActionExecuting logic within the PageTitle action filter and Unit Test the action filter itself?

Comment: @Spock I could have but the problem was then ActionFilterAttribute would only have worked if decorated on action method. I wanted the default values to be set/returned in case action was not applied with the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing (might be helpful for anyone facing similar problem).

1) I split up the code in the controller to below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        SetupMetadata(filterContext);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public virtual void SetupMetadata(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Page title
        var title = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false);
        if (title.Length == 1)
            ViewBag.Title = ((PageTitleAttribute)(title[0])).Parameter;
        else
            ViewBag.Title = "Default Page Title";
    }
}
```

2) Deriving my HomeController from the basecontroller.

3) And then unit tested it using:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void OnActionExecuting_should_return_attribute_value_when_set() 
    {
        var ctx = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();
        var controller = new HomeController();

        ctx.Setup(c => c.Controller).Returns(controller);
        ctx.Setup(c => c.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false)).Returns(new object[] { new PageTitleAttribute("Overriden Title") });

        controller.SetupMetadata(ctx.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual("Overriden Title", controller.ViewBag.Title);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OnActionExecuting_should_return_default_attribute_values_if_attributes_are_missing()
    {
        var ctx = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>();
        var controller = new HomeController();

        ctx.Setup(c => c.Controller).Returns(controller);
        ctx.Setup(c => c.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PageTitleAttribute), false)).Returns(new object[0]);

        controller.SetupMetadata(ctx.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual("Default Page Title", controller.ViewBag.Title);
    }
}
```